# Are source code of applications hosted on Appharbor available to public?

Tags: open-source, appharbor

I see appharbor is very promising alternative to windows azure. Are all the applications created there for trial are open source by default? If yes does deleting the application also deletes the source code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about using a third party service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use AppHarbor for free and keep your source code private.